# What is the correct name for the simulated greenery used to make wreaths for doll house furnishing?

Tags: material-identification, kids-crafts

When making a Christmas scene for a classic American home made dolls House using traditional Midwest home crafting skills, it is common to include a holly wreath.

What is the name given to green material in the picture below? It consists of short strips of plastic or foil wound into a twisted thread or wire. To simulate holly leaves or fir tree bows.

[image]

Similar to a foil Christmas garland that you would put on a Christmas tree, but greatly reduced in size (for image scale, about the size of a US silver dollar, roughly 1.6" diameter).

I'm asking about the product created from bound using twisted wire so that it looks like foliage. Not the green strips that it's make from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You described this material as "like a garland but smaller," and Google results for "miniature (pine) garland" seem to return exactly what you're looking for. If you specifically want to make dollhouse wreaths, you can look for "artificial Christmas garland ties," which are precut to the size of large twist-ties and made of stiff wire. Some of them should be approximately the correct width and length for a dollhouse wreath, but check the exact product for details.

Comment: Looks like you can find variations by mixing and matching those key words. e.g., "miniature christmas garland" also returned some dollhouse-scale versions.

Comment: Do you know what the name for the material that the artificial Christmas garland ties are made from, I need to know if I want to order it on a drum.

Comment: @AaarghZombies different materials, there is no generic name for it. Except maybe for "tinsel"

Comment: If there are different names, could I please have them.

Comment: @AaarghZombies They are all made of different *materials* such as nylon and such, but you said that's not what you're looking for. There is not a generic name for "green leafy-looking plastic stuff attached to wire, specifically narrow." There is "tinsel" or "pine tinsel", which comes in many sizes and colors and is often shiny, but not always (although "pine" will usually be green and not shiny).

Comment: @pine tinse, the answer is Pine Tinsel. That's all I needed.

Comment: @Joachim, sorry, I'd forgotten about this one. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Google:

- miniature Christmas leaf ribbon trim

This one includes tiny fir, mini holly and even green snowflake trim

you might also like:

- miniature Christmas leaf trim
- miniature Christmas leaf ribbon

There's also:

Leaf ribbon trim

For other kinds of leaves like oak etc

Answer (score -3):

Answer by way of @Esther is pine tinsel. Or to be more precise (X)mm pine tinsel.

Comment: Esther did the work of researching & posting, and came up with the term you were looking for, so it would be appropriate to suggest that Esther add that to their answer, and then accept that answer, rather than leaving a brusk comment and posting it as an answer yourself. BTW, what comes up in a search for pine tinsel doesn't look like the picture, and none of the links were dollhouse scale. Searches on some guesses for the "X"mm returned nothing. So this might be the term you had in your head but couldn't remember, but the terms in Esther's answer are what actually find the product in the Q.

Comment: @tagged them in, if they want to post an answer then I can select it. I found it first time after doing an image search, so it's the correct answer. They were 100% right as far as I'm concerned.